# In libgdx on Android, how do I save game state in case app is killed?

Tags: android, variables, libgdx, android-lifecycle

In Android, we usually save all of our **state variables** in the `onSaveInstanceState()` **callback** by putting them in the `Bundle` provided.

How do people deal with **saving/loading game state variables** with `libGDX` as the classes can't use/return a `Bundle` object?

Answer (score 4):

This is quit simple! You can use [Preferences](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) for that. You can store values in the Preferences. On android the backend uses the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) from Android itself. On desktop its saved as an xml somewhere in the user folder.

I wrote a simple Helper to save options and get the options of my game. Here is some code out of it. (Note, dont forget to flush after saving something)

```
public class PreferencesHelper {
    public final static String PREF_NAME_OPTION = "options";
    private final static String VOLUMEN = "volumen";
    private final static String VIBRATE = "vibrate";
    private final static String EFFECT_VOLUMEN = "effect";
    private final static String FIRST_START = "start";
    private Preferences optionPref = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREF_NAME_OPTION);;

    public PreferencesHelper() {
        optionPref = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREF_NAME_OPTION);
    }

    public float getVolumen() {
        return optionPref.getFloat(VOLUMEN);
    }

    public void setVolumen(float vol) {
        optionPref.putFloat(VOLUMEN, vol);
        optionPref.flush();
    }

    public boolean getVibrate() {
        return optionPref.getBoolean(VIBRATE);
    }

    public void setVibrate(boolean vibr) {
        optionPref.putBoolean(VIBRATE, vibr);
        optionPref.flush();
    }

    public float getEffectVolumen() {
        return optionPref.getFloat(EFFECT_VOLUMEN);
    }

    public void setEffectVolumen(float eff) {
        optionPref.putFloat(EFFECT_VOLUMEN, eff);
        optionPref.flush();
    }
}
```

This is how i save my options. To save an character you do the same but save all importand stuff you need, to recreate your character when loading the game again. You can also have more than one prefrerence!

I hope this helped.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So when the app is killed and recreated, I assume you check that the savedInstanceState Bundle is not null and pass that information to the ApplicationListener to determine whether or not to load the game state from the Preferences?

Comment: I do actually dont care about the saveInstanceBundle and also dont know if i can catch that in libgdx. Guess not. If its killed it get created and i get the states from the Preferences as a normal start. There is more or less something like the Main activity with different methodes like create(), resume() stop() as you know it from normal android. its inside the Core projekt and extends Game which actually is an ApplicationListener it does have the callbacks if i get that right. http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html. But this is the normal way to save char states for e

Comment: alright, thankyou, but this doesn't really answer my question.